# Transfer function of RLC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, transfer-function, passive-filter

I'm trying to find the transfer function but I'm a little bit confused about how to solve this. I can't solve for the two Ls in parallel

[image]

How I can know what type of filter is this? I think it's a low pass filter, but I don't now if the 2 Ls can change it.

I'm trying to do this one too. Is it the same as the first one? I have to solve this as two parallel Ls in series to each other?
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is just an exercise in impedance. 
$$
Z_R = R\\
Z_C = -j\frac{1}{\omega C} \\
Z_L = j\omega L
$$
After that, you just think of everything as "generalized resistors", solving it as regular resistor networks.

Answer (score 0):

I think   circuit on first picture is

LC low pass filter 2-order

two inductors is sequentially not parallel.

[image]

To search for a transfer function, this  circuit can be replaced with the following

[image]

Total inductance **L = L1 + L2**

In order to get a transfer function, need to write the differential input-output equation.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Due to the fact that there are only poles, there are no zeros,
with  an increase  frequency,    magnitude of the transfer function
should decrease   (after **frequency>[1/(LC)^0.5**].
Therefore, it is a Low Pass filter.

This is the second transfer function that I have ever tried to
find, I hope there are not too many mistakes :)

For analyze transfer function can use this document

http://web.mit.edu/2.14/www/Handouts/PoleZero.pdf

Comment: You can use the circuit tool to draw circuits, images don't look that great, this doesn't answer the question can you improve it?